# How is `class.name` implemented

Tags: angular

I can bind to existing `Node` properties like this:

```
<span [HTMLSpanElementProperty]='value'></span>
```

For example, I can bind to `style.color` like this:

```
<span [style.color]='green'></span>
```

This is valid with pure DOM as well:

```
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.color = 'green';
```

However, I can't do the same with `class.name`.

Does anyone know how `class.name` binding is implemented? Or where to look in the sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[class.name]`, `[style.name.unit]`, and `[attr.name]` are special Angular syntax. 
There is no support for any other properties and you also can't build your own. This is "hardcoded" into Angular.

Comment: yeah, thanks, this question is about implementation details though. And what is `style.name.unit`? Can you show an example?

Comment: What implementation details? `[style.width.%]="5"` or `[style.height.px]="50"` See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/95cbca20a5ffc44b0ff624830ada46f87c0b4346/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/binding_parser.ts#L271 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/95cbca20a5ffc44b0ff624830ada46f87c0b4346/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/binding_parser.ts#L26 This creates property binding in the template parser. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fcb4e664933f0b44c897e61be734581dfb10f088/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_ast.ts#L216

Comment: thanks, as I understand, these have nothing to do with ngClass and ngStyle directives?

Comment: No, they (`[class...],...`) are special Angular syntax. `ngStyle’ and `ngClass` are just plain normal directives as anybody can build with Angular. The only thing special about those is, that they are shipped with Angular.